# Trying to get a Jframe class and a Jcomponent class to interact when the user checks a JCheckBox

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So far I have it so the code creates two frames: a frame where the DrawingComponent is put and a frame with interactive buttons on it. Currently, the user can select between drawing a line, a rectangle, or an ellipse. I have MouseActionListener's set up for the DrawingComponent so drawing each shape individually works.

---

```
public class DrawingViewer extends JFrame {

private JFrame controlFrame;
private JButton drawButton, fillButton, undoButton; 
private JCheckBox lineBox, recBox, ellipseBox;
private JLabel drawLabel, fillLabel;
private DrawingComponent component;

public DrawingViewer () {
    setupThisFrame();       
    setupControlFrame();
    setupButtons();
    showFrames();   
}

....

 fillLabel = new JLabel();
    fillLabel.setOpaque(true);
    fillLabel.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN,12));
    fillLabel.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    fillLabel.setBackground(null);
    if(fillLabel.getBackground() != null){
        fillLabel.setText("         ");
    }
    else{
        fillLabel.setText(" nothing ");
    }

....

class shapeCheckListener implements ActionListener{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == lineBox){
            System.out.println("Line Chosen");
            component.setLine();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == recBox){
            System.out.println("Rectangle Chosen");
            component.setRec();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == ellipseBox){
            System.out.println("Ellipse Chosen");
            component.setEllipse();
        }
      }
   }    
}

----------------------------------------------------------
public class DrawingComponent extends JComponent {

private int mouseX;
private int mouseY;
private int mouseX2;
private int mouseY2;
public Shape shape; 
public Color borderColor;
public Color fillColor;

public DrawingComponent() {
    setupMouse();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    if(shape != null){
        g2.draw(shape);
    }
    else{
        shape = null;
    }

}

public void setLine(){
    shape = new Line2D.Double(mouseX, mouseY, mouseX2, mouseY2);
}
public void setRec(){
    shape = new Rectangle(Math.min(mouseX, mouseX2), Math.min(mouseY, mouseY2) , Math.abs(mouseX - mouseX2), Math.abs(mouseY - mouseY2));
}
public void setEllipse(){
    shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(Math.min(mouseX, mouseX2), Math.min(mouseY, mouseY2), Math.abs(mouseX - mouseX2), Math.abs(mouseY - mouseY2));
}
```

Comment: Where is javascript?

Answer (score 1):

The frame is just a shell. It shouldn't contain any data related to the app. In fact you don't even need to extend JFrame at all.

Your drawing areas should have method to change properties of the class. Then you can create a button panel that has access to the drawing area class. Whenever you want to change a shape you then just notify the drawing area of the change.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for examples of this approach. This example only has a "color" property that can be changed. So you your case you would need to add a "shape" property.